# Center for UIScreen.main , super.view and other views are not centered in middle of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, arkit, cgrect

My goal is to place a button at the center of an iPhone screen, so that the button is equally distant from the edges of the screen. I have attempted to add this button in two ways by assigning the frame an origin with the center of either the parent view, super.view or UIScreen.main. I have also tried using constraints to re-set the center of the button to the center of parent view. In both cases the button appears to be near the center of the screen but not directly centered. Things to note, I am using an ARSCNView and secondly I am not using .xib or storyboard to configure the UI. You can view a screen shot of the camera button(in red): 
[camera button not centered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccuO3.jpg)

You can look at what my current code looks like, in the view controller, here:  (I have commented out the various ways of defining the center of the screen)

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView()

func addCameraButton(){
   //let cameraCenter = CGPoint(x:super.view.center.x, y: super.view.center.y)
   //let cameraCenter = CGPoint(x:UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY)
    let cameraCenter = CGPoint(x:sceneView.center.x, y:sceneView.center.y)
    let cameraSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    let cameraRect = CGRect(origin: cameraCenter, size: cameraSize)
    cameraButton = KYShutterButton(frame:cameraRect, shutterType: .normal, buttonColor: UIColor.gray)
    cameraButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraSnap), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(cameraButton!)

    let verticalCenterCamera = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cameraButton, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

    let horizontalCenterCamera = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cameraButton, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalCenterCamera, horizontalCenterCamera])
    cameraButton?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: You have set the origin of the camera button to the centre of the screen but the origin is the top left of the button.  The constraints are not working because you need to do the following: `cameraButton?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.   You don't need to have `camerabutton?.layoutIfNeeded() if you are not doing anything with the frame of the button immediately.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth is right. If you're not using constraints, you can also set the center of the camera button like so: `self.cameraButton.center = self.sceneView.center`

Comment: I have successfully tried the above solutions and they all work exactly as desired except for one. For whatever reason after I set cameraButton?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false the size of the button shrinks. As far as moving the origin of the CGRect frame so that it's center is at the center of the screen, I ended up defining two variables for the x and y coordinates that are 50 points shy of the center x and y coordinate.        let xOrigin = sceneView.center.x - 50
let yOrigin = sceneView.center.y - 50
let cameraCenter = CGPoint(x:xOrigin, y: yOrigin) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With auto-layout you need to set `translateAutoresizingMaskIntoconstarints` to `false` when setting constraints programmatically

```
cameraButton?.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoconstarints = false
let verticalCenterCamera = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cameraButton, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let horizontalCenterCamera = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cameraButton, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalCenterCamera, horizontalCenterCamera])
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

//

With frame layout

```
self.view.addSubview(cameraButton!)
self.cameraButton?.center = self.sceneView.center
```